# Forwarding events to selected instance

Tags: c#, events, proxy, forwarding

Is there a good strategy to exchange the receiver of multiple events (let's say an object instance A) during runtime to another instance B (or multiple instances)? For example think of a menu bar with a bunch of operations that can be performed on the currently selected of multiple objects.

Now one option would be to connect all object's handlers to the click events and let the handlers filter out the relevant calls (by checking *if* the current instance is selected) or registering/unregistering the events on selection.

Another one would be to register the events to an object functioning as proxy like this (rough code):

```
class ClickEventProxy 
{
    private static ClickEventProxy selectedInstance; // <-- changend on selection

    public event EventHandler SomeEventToForward;
    public static void RaiseSomeEventToForward(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (selectedInstance.ClickedAddNewFrame != null)
            selectedInstance.ClickedAddNewFrame(sender, e);
    }
    ...
}
```

The sender-site would look like `SomeSource.Click += ClickEventProxy.RaiseSomeEventToForward;` and all receivers would subscribe to their instance of the proxy.

However handling the instances (e.g. by a global `<object, proxy instance>` dictionary) is a bit unconvenient and the whole thing looks a bit clumsy. So my question: Is there a more programmatic way to do so? Or is it itself bad practice proxying events by introducing another step and one should rather remove and readd the handlers? (Maybe this could be made better by using custom events and altering the invocation list...)